# Repetitive search in VB (Word)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a macro in Word to convert US spellings to UK. In summary, it looks like this:

US_spelling = analyze

UK-spelling = analyse

Call Spell_change (US_spelling, UK_spelling)

The Spell_change sub changes the spelling, adds a comment to the document, and adds 1 to a counter.

I repeat the above three lines, i.e. call the Spell_change sub, about 140 times (for 'program', 'dialog' etc).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Posting your *actual* code is very easy - you go to visual studio, you highlight it, you press ctrl-c, you come to SO, you paste.. and so long as there are at least 4 spaces at the start of a line it formats monospace etc.. Which surely must be easier than typing it out all again here and making typos/producing non-working code (unless you really do have a variable called analyze/analyse

Comment: And if you really did mean macro, then I'm concerned that this is `vba`, not `vb.net` so please examine your tags to ensure the question is tagged correctly

Comment: In either case (vba/vb.net), you should look into what an "array" and a "for loop" are

Comment: *"I have written a macro in Word"*. If that's true then this is a VBA question, not VB.NET. Please determine what language you're actually using, tag the question appropriately and use accurate language in the question.

Comment: You could use 'track changes' instead of comments, which would make for much faster execution. Also, what is the point of the counter?

Comment: @macropod I output counters to a little text file that summarises how many changes have been made etc

Comment: @macropod - just come back to this - sorry for delay - is there a limit to the number of terms I can put in StrFnd and StrRep?

Comment: Nominally, only VBA's string length limit - of ~2 billion (2^31) characters. Long before you get there, though, you'll run into VBA's limit of 64k per procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've changed the tag to refer to VBA, perhaps:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, StrRep As String, i As Long, Cmt As Comment, StrOut As String
StrFnd = "analyze,color,labor"
StrRep = "analyse,colour,labour"
StrOut = "US_spelling" & vbTab & "UK_spelling"
With ActiveDocument
  With .Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
      .Text = Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
      .Replacement.Text = Split(StrRep, ",")(i)
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      If .Found = True Then StrOut = StrOut & vbCr & Split(StrFnd, ",")(i) & vbTab & Split(StrRep, ",")(i)
    Next
  End With
  Set Cmt = .Comments.Add(Range:=.Range(0, 0), Text:=StrOut & vbCr & "Total: " & UBound(Split(StrOut, vbCr)))
  With Cmt
    .Author = ""
    With .Range.Paragraphs
      .First.Range.Font.Bold = True
      .Last.Range.Font.Bold = True
    End With
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code inserts a comment at the top of the document with a record of all words found & changed, plus a count of those words (but not how many times each word was replaced).