# Word VBA Search for All Array Values

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word, find-replace

I have an array of words, and I want to be able to execute selection.find for any of them.

The array is just the product of a previous string, so

```
myarray() = split(mystring, ", ")
```

So, for example, if the array had the words a, b, and c, I want to search for the next instance of a, b, or c.

Is there any way I can do something like
`selection.find.text = array(0 to UBound)`
, where each time the macro is triggered, it finds the next closest array value?

I hope that makes sense, and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712118/using-functions-in-vba-in-ms-word-to-find-replace-strings-from-an-array

Comment: Or, for something likely to be closer to your 'mystring' usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66133780/repetitive-search-in-vb-word/66145166#66145166

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions but these are both for find and replace - I was hoping to make a macro for just finding and highlighting the words.